Jetpack Compose NavGraphBuilder uses composable as a method parameter. How?
This is from an Android compass app project at https://github.com/AkarshGuptaa/Compass.git which compiles and runs without bugs
I'm wanting to know how compassComposable: @Composable () -> Unit is passed to the HomeScreen composable function when none of the calls to this function provide the "compassComposable" parameter
Here is a portion of the code
NavHost(
    modifier = modifier,
    navController = navController,
    startDestination = startDestination,
){
    composable(ScreenRoutes.Home.name){
        HomeScreen( // <- call to home screen (without compassComposable parameter)
        degrees = degrees,
        isMagneticFieldSensorPresent = isMagneticFieldSensorPresent,
        onMenuClick = { navController.navigate(ScreenRoutes.WidgetSelection.name )}
        ){..}
        ..       
    }

    composable(ScreenRoutes.WidgetSelection.name){ // but somehow this is correctly passed to the HomeScreen composable function HOW??
        ..
        WidgetScreen( ..
        )
    }
}

But the HomeScreen Composable fun has a compassComposable parameter that is never supplied.

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
     modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
     degrees: Int, // observe this
     isMagneticFieldSensorPresent: Boolean,
     onMenuClick: () -> Unit = {},
     compassComposable: @Composable () -> Unit // Correctly points to the right navGraph composable but since it is never passed to the function when called, how does this happen?? 
     )  {
        ...
        compassComposable() // correctly displays the selected compass widget
        ..
        }


I've tried to trace it through the debugger but the "magic" seems to be happening in the background


This is made possible with the help of trailing lambda syntax on Kotlin
Trailing lambda as the name says, is a lamda function that is the last (trailing) parameter in a function
So, let's say you have a function foo
fun foo(a:Int, b:Int, c:()->Unit){
   // Do something
}

If you notice, we have a lambda function as the last parameter, so you can call this like so, right?
fun main(){
  foo(a= 1, b=2 ,c ={
       // Do something 
        })
}

You can make this even more visually easy to read by the trailing lambda syntax like so
fun main(){
  foo(a=1, b=2){
    // This is provided to the parameter C 

    // Do something 
  }
}

Good read on the docs can be found here

Thanks heaps, made my day :) I thought there must be some syntax magic going on but I didn't know what to google for. Trailing lambda, now I know :) Thanks!
